# I need to split an Oracle SQL script

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I need to modify an Oracle SQL file by splitting it into two files, but I have zero experience with Oracle. Here's what I have now:

**linkload.bat**

```
SQLPLUSW /nolog @linkload.txt
```

**linkload.txt**

```
CONNECT ABC/abcnumber1s2@defghi2;

spool E:\DataLoad\MovDataProductionJob\updclust.log;

select systimestamp start_time from dual;

@E:\DataUpd\UpdClust.sql

-- call load_schedule();

select systimestamp updclust_end_time from dual;

----comment/ uncomment following for disabling/ enabling load or schedule load depends on count

 call load_schedule_10G();

select systimestamp end_time from dual;

--spool off;

disconnect;

exit;
```

I need to split linkload.txt so that first file contains the functionality right up to and including the `@E:\DataUpd\UpdClust.sql` line, and the second file contains all the functionality after. I realize it's not as simple as just breaking the file apart, and through circumstances beyond my control, I don't have access to SQLDeveloper or even a development server to try this on. So that's why I'm bringing it to StackOverflow.

Here's what I came up with:

**linkload.bat**

```
SQLPLUSW /nolog @linkload1.txt
SQLPLUSW /nolog @linkload2.txt
```

**linkload1.txt**

```
CONNECT ABC/abcnumber1s2@defghi2;

spool E:\DataLoad\MovDataProductionJob\updclust.log;

select systimestamp start_time from dual;

@E:\DataUpd\UpdClust.sql

--spool off;

disconnect;

exit;
```

**linkload2.txt**

```
CONNECT ABC/abcnumber1s2@defghi2;

-- call load_schedule();

select systimestamp updclust_end_time from dual;

----comment/ uncomment following for disabling/ enabling load or schedule load depends on count

call load_schedule_10G();

select systimestamp end_time from dual;

disconnect;

exit;
```

Does that look correct? The think I'm most uncertain about is the `spool` command and if it needs to be in both files. Like I said before, I don't really have a way to test this before it goes into a staging environment. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need the spool command in the second script as well, since that's what tells sqlplus to save the output of the SELECTs to a file.  But the spool command in the second script will need the APPEND parameter, else it will overwrite the output from the first file.

Comment: Thanks. I made the change, and that seems to make sense. I have sent it to a DBA in my organization to execute on our staging database.

Comment: @Joe, I do believe that worked. If you want to submit an answer based on your comment, I will upvote and mark it accepted.

Comment: Cool; glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the spool command in the second script as well, since that's what tells sqlplus to save the output of the SELECTs to a file. But the spool command in the second script will need the APPEND parameter, else it will overwrite the output from the first file.